# Mysql-Link resource

Tags: php, mysql

Everytime I make a INSERT query using PHP, I get this error: "supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource"

Even so, the query works perfectly and the data is always inserted in the database.

Should I worry about that?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT-> here is the query

functions.php

```
function connect(){

    $h='myip';

    $un='popguest';

    $pw='mypassword';

    $connection = mysql_connect($h, $un, $pw, false);

    if(!$connection){

            die('Error connecting to database: ' . mysql_error());

    }

    mysql_set_charset('uf8',$connection);

    return $connection;

}
```

promoter.php

```
require_once("../functions/functions.php");
$f = new functions();
$f->connect();

$username=$_COOKIE["username"];
$p=$_GET['p'];

mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
$result3 = mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO popguest.guest (username, promoter) VALUES ('$username', '$p')");
```

Comment: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/111512/warning-mysql_query-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-link-resource-in-home

Comment: Post  your insert code please.

Comment: $result3 = mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO popguest.guest (username, promoter) VALUES ('$username', '$p')");

Comment: The notice you are getting is not from the 3 lines above, though it may be from the `functions.php` include, or in the `$f->connect()`.  My guess is you are calling something like `mysql_close()` somewhere when the link resource has already been closed, or you are using a connection resource in the wrong scope. Either way, more code needed.

Comment: it'd be great to give us the exact line where the error occurs (error_reporting & display_errors set)

Comment: You may need to print what exact value of $username and $p which are included in your query. Make sure that they are all valid value, because your code above has no problem.

Comment: Hi! My answer solve your problem? If so check as "correct", if not tell me what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$connection = mysql_connect($h, $un, $pw);
```

Try:

```
$f = new functions();
$link = $f->connect();
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['username']);
$p = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['p']);
$result3 = mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO popguest.guest (username, promoter) VALUES ('$username', '$p')",$link);
```

Comment: please do NOT try this unless you escaped all your super globals somewhere before this

Answer (score 0):

Are you escaping the data you insert?

Look at this if using MYSQLi:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

otherwise, look here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

You should always escape data before submitting it to a database as a rule :)

Hope this helps!